# How to get Location in WebView

Tags: android

In my MainActivity i can take Location with code like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
private Location currentLocation;

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(broadcastReceiver == null){
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                currentLocation = (Location)intent.getExtras().get("coordinates");
            }
        };
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));
}
```

Now i have `WebView` in this Activity and want to send Location to JavaScript inside `WebActivity`.

To send something from `Java` code to JS code inside `WebActivity` i crate webinterface class and use code like:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String GetHi(){
    return "Hi";
}
```

But how can i send Location?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the good old Json to pass the data to the Javascript side (The Dark Side henceforth). Serialize your data and pass it as a serialized JSON string to your Dark Side side and then in the Dark Side you can deserialize it into your Javascript Location object.